# Swift - Add an loading alert before open next view

Tags: ios, swift, view, load, alert

I have a View Controller that takes its time to load, so, when I click a button or link to go to that View, I want to show an Alert message for the user to wait because the view is loading.

How I do that? I can't close the alert from another view.

Here is my code:

class ViewControllerDetalleCliente:

```
@IBAction func verCrearPedido(_ sender: Any) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Cargando...", preferredStyle: .alert)  
    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
    let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let next:ViewControllerPedidoArticulos = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PedidoArticulos") as! ViewControllerPedidoArticulos
    next.nuevoPedido = true
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
}
```

class ViewControllerPedidoArticulos:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Where or how do I have to put the `.dismiss` function?

Comment: you can use MBProgressHUD with text

Comment: You would be better off displaying a activity view or something in the. Set view controller and simply hiding it when the loading has finished. Make sure you are loading the data asynchronously so that the view controller displays quickly.

Comment: call your method in **viewWillDisappear** before leave the view.

Comment: @iDeveloper I tried the viewWillDisappear method but it doesn't work...

Comment: any error occur or something else ?

Comment: @bey23 The main problem in your code is you are presenting the alertController and pushing the next view at same time don't do that check [my below solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43045050/6433023) once for that

Comment: @iDeveloper No, it just stay in the first view. I've change the alert `present` after call `pushViewController` and that did not work either.

Comment: @NiravD Hey, I already tried your code too. It is not exactly what i was looking for, I want to show the alert before the second view is loaded. I do many functions in `viewWillAppear` method and with your way when I click the button just appear the second view and then show the alert.

Comment: can you share your code  demo ?

Comment: @bey23 If you want to show indicator before pushing the nextController, Then when you make your async request? It is batter if you show indicator where you are making the async request.

Comment: @NiravD I did it some time ago, I put the loaded data in `viewDidLoad` but the data is not shown when the view appears cause I'm working with `tableView` and filling it while I call my functions. So, my second view takes twenty seconds to load (more or less) and that's why I want to do it that way.

Comment: @bey23 That the same thing I saying what you need is you need to first move to that controller and show the indicator before making your request and the simply dismiss it when you get response, if you want to not show anything inside the Controller then you can hide your tableview and show when you dismiss the controller.

Comment: @NiravD Ah ok sorry! I'm trying that now. I will answer you later.

Comment: @bey23 Will wait for your response.

Comment: @NiravD Finally I get it!! Thanks for your idea! I'm going to answer my own question.

Comment: @NiravD Yes, but I have to use threads and therefore it doesn't work with AlertController. I will put my answer to help everyone, if you don't mind of course.

Comment: @bey23 Its completely up to you if its helps you can put it.

Comment: @NiravD Yeah, I'm going to do that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thank you guys for all the answers. The key was thinking in other way, you shouldn't show the alert in the first view and close it in the second view. You should:

1. Go to second view
2. Open alert loading (it doesn't work, I used `UIActivityIndicatorView` instead. Add it with storyboard and create the variable) and start to load all data. In my case I have to use `DispatchQueue.main.async`to fill the tableView and finally `.reloadData()`
3. When is loaded, close alert loading.

Expecially thanks to [@NiravD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43045050/6433023) for that idea.

My code:

```
@IBOutlet var cargando: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        cargando.stopAnimating()
        cargando.isHidden = true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cargando.startAnimating()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            ... // load data 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the `ActivityIndicator` in `ViewControllerPedidoArticulos` then you need to put the `ActivityIndicator` inside that controller. Show the `AlertController` with your indicator where you are making any async request after that when you get response dismiss the controller.

So first remove the `ActivityIndicator` code from your button action.

```
@IBAction func verCrearPedido(_ sender: Any) {

    let next = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PedidoArticulos") as! ViewControllerPedidoArticulos
    next.nuevoPedido = true
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
}
```

After that inside `ViewControllerPedidoArticulos` controller add that code before you are making any async request or you can add it inside the `viewDidLoad` if you are making request in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Show the indicator with alertController
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Cargando...", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
    let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
    loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

    alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

Now simply call the `dismiss` where you getting response of your async request.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass `UIAlertController` object to next view controller like this:

```
  let next:ViewControllerPedidoArticulos = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PedidoArticulos") as! ViewControllerPedidoArticulos
    next.nuevoPedido = true
    next.objAlert = alert
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next, animated: true)
```

And in your next view controller's `viewDidLoad` dismiss that alert like:

```
func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)  

   if let alert = objAlert as! UIAlertController{
     alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this but I am writing the simplest way using closure.

Step 1 : make closure in 'ViewControllerPedidoArticulos' class

```
 let stopActivityBlock : (()->())?
```

Step 2: set Its call back code

```
next.stopActivityBlock = { () in
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Step 3:

call it from 'ViewControllerPedidoArticulos' class's viewDidLoad method.

```
class ViewControllerPedidoArticulos:

func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    if stopActivityBlock != nil{
    stopActivityBlock()
}
}
```

Comment: I'm trying it but the `next.stopActivityBlock = { in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }` give me a error: Expected expression

Comment: Sorry, There was one small syntax mistake in closure definition (Step : 2) please check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to hand-in the alert view controller to the second view controller, and dismiss it there. Something like:

```
@IBAction func verCrearPedido(_ sender: Any) {
    // ...
    next.alertVC = alert
    // push
}
```

class ViewControllerPedidoArticulos:

```
var alertVC:UIAlertController?

// viewDidLoad or maybe better:
func viewDidLoad(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)        
    self.alertVC?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, I think it was a great idea, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Maybe `viewDidLoad` is not the correct place to dismiss it. You might need to dismiss it "after the calculations have been completed" (on the main thread; use `DispatchQueue.main.async`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party pod library "SVProgressHUD" which i usually use when loading some data from API in order to perform a loading view to the user.

Simply install the pod in ur podfile and import in your class using

```
import SVProgressHUD
```

After that simply use the following code to use the loading indicator while your app does some work in background.

```
//Loading progress ui until the data is retrieved from the server
    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Loading...")

//After completing the retrieval of data from server
 SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
```

Its very easy and looks great. The only pre-requisite is that you should know how to install pods/cocoapods

I hope it helped. Cheers.

Comment: Is there no other way to do it without using libraries?

Comment: Honestly, i have not tried any other way to achieve this as i found this the easiest of all. I am sure there must be other way arounds too. I hope you get the required answer in comments. :]